# How can I handle the response from the retrofit (Here my response not showing the data, it only shows the code and status of the call)

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to do the api call from my android app. But the response shows the status code 200 with ok message.
But the data for the call is return by httpClient.
So how can I handle the response data of my call.
Here the response will be

request payload

**/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"data":{"email":"foobar@gmail.com","password":"PASSWoRD121"}}**

response:

**okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"data":"my tokken"}**

Here is my printed response will not give the above data. How can I set the token to my next calls?

**response ==== Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url="http://tyhgfhfty/hfhgfh/"}**

```
ApiService.java

 @POST(ApiConstant.Login)
 Call<User> LoginRequest(@Body JsonObject user);
```

LoginActivity:

```
ApiService userLoginService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        final JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();

        jo.addProperty(ApiParameter.EMAIL, email);
        jo.addProperty(ApiParameter.PASSWORD, password);
        final JsonObject jobj = new JsonObject();
        jobj.add(ApiParameter.DATA, jo);
        userLoginService.userLogin(jobj).enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginRequest> call, Response<LoginRequest>response) {
                System.out.println(("response ===" + response));
```

LoginRequest.java

```
public class LoginRequest {

private String email;
private String password;

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

}

Comment: You can get the token from `response.getBody();` by parsing the JSON

Comment: Can you let me know getBody is from which dependencies. I am getting only response.body() and it returns null

Comment: Oh sorry, it is `response.body()`. Provide your User class code.

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA Modified the User.java to LoginRequest.java. Can you look into the above code? Now getting the response as mypackagename.LoginRequest@edfafe9

Comment: If your json response is `{"data":"my tokken"}` your LoginRequest class should have `private String data;` and the setter getter

Comment: I have modified as private String data; with Getter Setter. Still I am getting the response.body as **mypackagename.LoginRequest@dcc373b**.

Comment: Access it through the `getData()`, it should be `response.body().getData()`

Comment: Hey Thanks, Yes the above gives my token as String. Can you clarify this. I have another response as {"data": {"user": "xxxx", "email": "foobar@gmail.com", "lastname": "yyyyy", "gender": 1, "deviceType": 1}"}. **For this shall i need to add all the values as private String data; private int deviceType; etc with getter setter method.**

Comment: I have posted the answer with the little explanation about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a json response, you can analyze or presume **a json is equal a class**, because Gson convertion.

In that json is containing a key `data` and a string `my tokken`.

In a class retrofit response it is equal variable named `data` which is from key `data` with type `String`,  why String? because value my tokken is a string in that json. So you can retrieve that value later from `data` getter setter. Like `getData();`

So for  `{"data":"my tokken"}`, your `LoginResponse` class only contain one field that is `data` with type `String` and the setter getter.

When you have response `{"data": {"user": "xxxx", "email": "foobar@gmail.com", "lastname": "yyyyy", "gender": 1, "deviceType": 1}"}`. You can analyze that key `data` contain a json object; **a json equal a class**.

So, you need a class to get accessibility to it value. Let's say it `User` class.

```
public class User {

     private String user; // because the value of user in json is String
     private String email;
     private String lastname;
     private Int gender; // because the value of gender in json is Int
     private Int deviceType;

     // the setter getter here

}
```

Last, your class response that handle the retrofit call. Let say `UserResponse` should be like this

```
public class UserResponse {

     private User data; 
     // the variable is named data because it should be the same to the json key and the type of the variable is class `User`. Remember about the bolded text
     // (variable named same is not a must, if different, you can use `SerializedName` annotation, you can read about it later) 

     // the setter getter here

}
```

I explained in simple way of my thinking, i hope you understand about it.